# How to make menu pop up when user right clicks an item in a JList?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JList with Strings in it that takes up the whole area of the JFrame. The problem is that when the user right clicks it doesn't have to be over an item in the JFrame. It pops up just whenever an item is selected. So you can just click anywhere and then right click anywhere and the menu will pop up. How do I make it so that the menu only pops up when the user right click over an item in the JList? This is what I have so far:

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
            {
                JList list = (JList) e.getSource();
                int row = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                list.setSelectedIndex(row);

                if(list.getSelectedIndex() != -1)
                {
                    PopUpMenu menu = new PopUpMenu();
                    menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Code looks reasonable, except you should be using aJPopupMenu  when using Swing. Not sure I understand the problem. Post a proper [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: If the `JList` takes up the whole screen, then clicking anywhere on the list will generate the mouse event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
        {
            JList list = (JList) e.getSource();

            int preferredHeight = list.getPreferredSize().height;
            int mouseHeight = e.getPoint().y;

            if (mouseHeight > preferredHeight)
                return;

            int row = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
            list.setSelectedIndex(row);
            // show JPopupMenu
        }
    }
});
```

It will ignore mouse events below the last item in the list.

Comment: have to test SelectionModel.isSelected > -1 && SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton rather than programatically to force the selection